# C# Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Action<string>'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run a method on every instance in my list, but when I try to do that using ".foreach()" method, I'm getting an error

> "Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Action'"

My method that I'm trying to call

```
public static string CheckSerial(List <string> serial, IWebDriver Driver)
{
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukdhs1/product-support/servicetag/" + serial);
    return Driver.Title;
}
```

My main method

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{       
    IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    List<string> serials = new List<string>
    {
        "JPV6Q12",
        "JPV7Q12"
    };
    serials.ForEach(CheckSerial(serials, driver));
};
```

Thank you all in advance for any help on this one,
Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List<string>.ForEach` is expecting as a parameter an `Action<string>` but that is not what you are passing it.

You should be calling it this way:

```
public static string CheckSerial(string serial, IWebDriver Driver)
{
    Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.dell.com/support/home/uk/en/ukdhs1/product-support/servicetag/" + serial);
    return Driver.Title;
}

serials.ForEach(s => CheckSerial(s, driver));
```

but it seems to me strange that you do nothing with the return value. If you want to use it and the `GoToUrl` doesn't throw an exception in case of invalid url, then you could:

```
var result = serials.Select(s => new { Serial = s, Title = CheckSerial(s, driver) });
```

---

If you do want to make the `ForEach` to work similar to how you initially did then you can make the `CheckSerial` an extension method and:

```
public static void CheckSerial(this IWebDriver Driver, string serial) { ... }
serials.ForEach(driver.CheckSerial);
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Forgot to add that I will be storing results from called method in a list, so I've got a list of every web title for every serial that I have got. After fixing my code It works like a charm, and I do understand what I have done wrong. Thank you so much for your help, Gilad!